# How to getContext() in LIBGDX android app

Tags: android, android-activity, libgdx, android-context

I need to get the `Context` of my app but in my main Class extends from `Game` so I can not extends from `Activity`. Does anybody know how to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: Please post what have you tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfacing is the way to go since you can't access **Android** specific code from **Core** module.

**Step 1: Create the interface (CORE MODULE)**

```java
public interface MyInterface {

    void manipulateContext();

    void manipulateContextWithExtraParams(String example, int example2);
}
```

**Step 2: Implement the interface (ANDROID MODULE)**

```java
import android.content.Context;

public class InterfaceImplementation implements MyInterface {

    private Context context;

    public InterfaceImplementation(Context context) {
        // Store the context for later use
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void manipulateContext() {
        // Do something with the context, this is called on the core module
        System.out.println(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void manipulateContextWithExtraParams(String example, int example2) {
        if (example2 == 1) {
            System.out.println(example + context);
        } else {
            System.out.println(example);
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 3: Send the implemented interface your game (ANDROID MODULE)**

```java
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
import com.frontanilla.helping.getcontext.InterfaceImplementation;
import com.frontanilla.helping.getcontext.MyGame;

public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();

        InterfaceImplementation interfaceImplementation = new InterfaceImplementation(this);

        // Here we send the implementation to our Game in Core module
        initialize(new MyGame(interfaceImplementation), config);
    }
}
```

**Step 4: Store and use the methods you defined on your interface (CORE MODULE)**

```java
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;

public class MyGame extends Game {

    private MyInterface myInterface;

    public MyGame(MyInterface myInterface) {
        // Store for later use
        this.myInterface = myInterface;
    }

    @Override
    public void create() {
        // Example of manipulating the Android Context indirectly from Core module
        myInterface.manipulateContext();
        myInterface.manipulateContextWithExtraParams("Hello", 2);
    }
}
```

As you can see, you will not be manipulating the `Context` from the core module directly, instead, place that logic on the `InterfaceImplementation` class

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! They key was to access the `context` in the `AndroidLauncher` which is the only class that extends `AndroidApplication`

Answer (score 2):

LibGDX is a cross-platform game engine, so your application can be executed on multiple platforms. Only Android, which is just one supported platform, can provide a `Context` object.

To get around this issue, you'll need to create an `Interface` in the core module of your LibGDX project. That Interface can, for example, contain a `getContext()` method. Add the interface as an argument in the constructor of your main LibGDX class. In every platform-specific module, you should then implement this `Interface` , override the `getContext()` method (by returning a `Context` object in the android module and `null` in every other module) and pass it with the constructor for the main LibGDX class in the Launcher class for that module.

For more information about the topic, read the LibGDX Wiki: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code

**EDIT:**
LibGDX isn't able to handle the `Context` object, you'll need to manipulate the `Context` object in the Android module, instead of passing it to the core module! Thanks to @Nicolas and @Luis Fernando Frontanilla for mentioning this.

Comment: This won't work as the interface needs to be in the core module which has no dependency on android, therefore no knowledge of the Context type. Instead, he might want to have methods such as `getString` or whatever in the interface that will call Context in the android module implementation.

Comment: Interfacing is the way to go but the person who asked will need to have a method in the interface to manipulate or use the `Context` instance. This interface will need to be implemented **on the android module**

Comment: Well, I can create an Interfaz with `getContext()`method but this would be the same that add the class to the Android module and import the libraries for the `Context` from Android. The problem is that those clases don't have a Context so I can't use `Context context = this` in any place... I don't know if I am getting wrong in any point...

Comment: Made the clarification comment I was gonna post into a full answer, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

What I have tried is:

`scoreHelper = new ScoreSQLiteHelper(context,"dbtest",null,1);
 db = scoreHelper.getWritableDatabase();`

but I don't have any context to feed that method.

It would be usefull any other way to get a path to create the db with:

`db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(path,null);`

Comment: Well, as I pointed out in my answer, you'll need to create an `Interface`. In your original post you didn't mention the database. If this is your goal however, the `Interface` should contain a method `getDatabase()` or something simular. Implement the `Interface` in the Android module by overriding the `getDatabase()` method with the code you posted above and some other code to manipulate it. LibGDX doesn't know what a `SQLiteDatabase` is, so you can't return that object. In every other module, `getDatabase()` should return null.

Comment: Okey, but how do you override the `getContext()`method? what do you put inside? Because as far as I know you only can acces to the `context` if your main class extends from the `Application` class